# multiple Async method call taking time to execute

Tags: c#, .net, performance, asynchronous

I am checking to improve my application performance. There is a method where nine methods are called one by one to communicate with service that fetch data from different tables. All these nine calls are asynchronous. So it should not consume much time from main thread, but It is taking more than 3 secs to execute that is a major part of the time consumed in loading my form. How can i reduce this time consumption.

#### Update:

I am using MVP pattern. In this case I call presenter methods one by one, presenter is communicating with WPF service by proxy and my proxy is having signature for Sync and Async methods which are called using independent methods of presenter. In this case all nine methods are Async But it is taking too much time for this method, 2 secs are not too much but it is major part of the total time consumed in loading the page.

Comment: How do you call these asynchronous methods?

Comment: I think you don't call these methods asychrounous at all - if you did the time till you got all the data would still be 3sec. or more but it wouldn't slow down your form load by any observable amount of time

Comment: Could you please show us the snippets in which you are making the async call to the service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the nine methods are all making HTTP requests to the same host, you may find that you're running into problems because only two HTTP requests to the same host are permitted concurrently by default. One option would be to raise that limit (you can do so in app.config) and another would be to change the protocol (if you can) to pass *all* the operations in one request, and let the server decide how to do the operations concurrently. That would simplify the client-side operation, to start with.

Comment: @jon-skeet - Is the two requests a client thing? I thought that was a browser specific thing e.g. it affects silverlight apps.

Comment: @Shaun: It's up to the process, but the .NET HTTP client library enforces it by default too.

Comment: @jon-skeet - thanks for the clarification; what .config setting would that be?

Answer (score 1):

Even if the requests are executed asynchronously you still have to wait for a connection to be established.

Whatever the reasons, you should be able to push the method that starts those requests onto the Threadpool or a TPL Task. That ought to solve your Form loading delay.

Answer (score 0):

3 seconds is not too much time, anyway if starting your asynchronous methods cause the form to be slower in when loading, then I suggest you to execute that code in the form load or constructor in another thread or timer that you start it after the form is finish loading, so executing your operations will not effect form load time.